# Hangs on run and exits only with CTRL + C

Tags: windows, docker

These are our images:

```
PS C:\Users\bigfo> docker images                                                                                                                          
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE                                                                      
mongo               latest              71c101e16e61        12 days ago         358MB                                                                     
mongo               <none>              88b7188af865        2 weeks ago         358MB                                                                     
hello-world         latest              1815c82652c0        3 weeks ago         1.84kB
```

These are our containers:

```
PS C:\Users\bigfo> docker ps -a                                                                                                                           
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS               NAMES                  
2b2b2d73559d        mongo               "docker-entrypoint..."   6 days ago          Exited (128) 6 days ago                       some-mongo             
678d1e4a4b0c        hello-world         "/hello"                 2 weeks ago         Exited (0) 2 weeks ago                        eager_turing
```

This is our docker version:

```
PS C:\Users\bigfo> docker -v
Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87
```

The following hangs:

```
PS C:\Users\bigfo> docker run hello-world
```

Two questions:

1. How can we troubleshoot this?
2. How can we resolve this?

We're on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows the fix was to restart Docker.

First quit docker ...

[image: Quit docker via the task bar.]

... then start the daemon from a shell (such as PowerShell) ...

```
PS> & "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Docker for Windows.exe"
```